# how to read data stored in blobs

Tags: sql, postgresql, blob

my application datbase in postgressql and from the document i understand that it store few data in a blob and from the table i can only get the oid of it.

is there any possibility to read the content from these blobs? if yes, could someone share the knowhow?

Comment: In most of the cases `bytea` is the better choice to store blobs.

Answer (score 1):

From the OID, a file with the contents of the large object can be exported.

Either client-side (psql):

```
  \lo_export oid-to-export /path/to/a/file
```

Or server-side in SQL (creates the file on the server, beware that postgres must have the permission to write into the destination directory).

```
   SELECT lo_export(oid-to-export, '/path/to/a/file');
```